# Is the HSync and VSync signal level kept high after data period or are they present only during single cycle

Tags: xilinx, hdmi

I'm trying to understand HDMI specification for my toy project on Zybo. I'm trying to understand when I get HSync and VSync signals.

- I get them once. That means I don't need to look back on previous value - if I read the signal it mean that I get a new line
- H/VSync is kept high through the whole period after end of line

Also will I get a VSync without HSync or will they be separate?

Comment: Um, does HDMI carry vsync/hsync at all? In my understanding, HDMI just carries digital data with separate information on how to divide that data into frames and lines; vsync and hsync are things that your HDMI receiver design generates, so your question is unanswerable, because we don't know what you did to receive HDMI in the FPGA.

Comment: @MarcusMüller as far as I know it is carried by controls of blue channel. It might help if channel get out of sync I guess and size does not match. That said documentation seems to mix and match DVI and HDMI freely which does not exactly help me (and the former do carry vsync/hsync in digital form).

Comment: there's no "blue" channel in HDMI. HDMI is just pixel data – the way these bits are reconstructed into pixels of color is up to the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HDMI Specification Version 1.4a](http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/specification.aspx), the length of `Vsync` is 5 lines. Each line has `Hactive + Hblank` clock cycles (e.g. 1920+830 for 1080p/24Hz fp). The length of `Hsync` changes between 40 and 44 clock cycles for the 3D video formats.

Indeed, designers should not rely on the lengths of `Vsync` and `Hsync` signals. A common approach is to internally generate single cycle pulses when the incoming signals are asserted or deasserted. In addition, some devices don't send `Hsync` signal. This is not compliant to the standard, but a reality.

Answer (score -1):

I have finally found the answer at [fpga4fun](http://www.fpga4fun.com/HDMI.html), which contains implementation of source:

```
wire hSync = (CounterX>=656) && (CounterX<752);
wire vSync = (CounterY>=490) && (CounterY<492);
wire DrawArea = (CounterX<640) && (CounterY<480);
```

It looks like `hSync` and `vSync` are kept high for the whole offscreen area. Therefore HDMI sink must accept that.

Comment: ah, so this is totally unrelated to HDMI in general, but very specific to a specific piece of FPGA implementation at a fixed resolution!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I saw it in many HDMI implementations so I would think it is popular.

Comment: it might be, but the code you've pasted is from *one specific* implementation, and depends on a fixed resolution.  So, this is absolutely nothing to be generalized for more than this specific HDMI implementation, *which you don't even name*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That was closest what I could find out and it kind of answered my question - it is legal for source to keep the signal high so I need to handle it in sink.

Comment: "So, this is absolutely nothing to be generalized for more than this specific HDMI implementation, which you don't even name." - well the HDMI implementation on Zybo board?

Comment: There's no "HDMI implementation on Zybo". That's some HDL code that **you** chose to synthesize and run on the FPGA; maybe it's some example, I don't know, but it certainly has a name!
It would be an OK answer (and an OK question) if you could *anywhere* mention what HDMI implementation you use. Other HDMI implementations simply won't have nets called `CounterX` or so, so this simply doesn't help anyone but yourself

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh, I see. No, the `CounterX` does not appear in my implementation. However the fact that source may behave in that way means that me as a sink need to handle it. I hope that I clarified the answer.